# How to change LineChart line colour to a gradient dynamically based on point value?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am building an application in WPF (C#) to accept a list of numeric values and display them in the form of a line chart. I am using the WPF toolkit from Codeplex for this purpose.

I want the line chart to change colour as a gradient from blue to red as the value goes from 125 to 145. I have used a overridden LineDataPoint style with a ValuetoColorConverter to change the colour of the data points but I don't know how to set the gradient for the lines between the points.

Also, the legend icon colours appear blank.

**The XAML:**

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries                 
   Title="Systolic Pressure"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}"
   IndependentValuePath="recdatetime"
   DependentValuePath="systolic">

   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
       <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource fullTooltips}">
           <Setter Property="Background">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <Binding Path="systolic" Converter="{StaticResource BPToColorConverter}">
                       <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                           <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                       </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                   </Binding>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>           
       </Style>
   </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>

   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
       <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis
         x:Name="systolic_chart_yaxis"
         Orientation="Y"
         Title="BP (mmHg)"
         Minimum="50"
         Interval="5"
         ShowGridLines="True"/>
   </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
       <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis
          Orientation="X"
          Name="mainchart_timeaxis" 
          Interval="1"
          IntervalType="Days"
          ShowGridLines="False">
        </chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis>
   </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
```

There are two such line series. The above code provides the day X-axis on the top while the other provides the hour X-axis on the bottom.

**The ColorConverter**

```
 public class BPToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int input = (int)value;
        int r, g, b;
        SolidColorBrush valuecolor;
        if((int)parameter==1) //systolic
        { 
            if(input>=125)
            {
                if(input>145) input=145;
                r = (int)(((float)(input-125)/20) * 255);
                g = 0;
                b = 255 - r;
            }
            else if(input<110)
            {
                if(input<90) input=90;
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = (int)(((float)(110 - input) / 25) * 255);
                b = 255 - b;
            }
            else
            {
                r=0;
                g=0;
                b=255;
            }

        }
        else //diastolic
        {
            if (input > 85)
            {
                if (input > 100) input = 100;
                r = (int)(((float)(input - 85) / 15) * 77);
                r += 102;
                g = (int)(((float)(input - 85) / 15) * 128);
                g = 255 - g;
                b = 0;
            }
            else if (input < 75)
            {
                if (input < 65) input = 65;
                r = ((int)((float)(input - 65) / 10) * 25);
                r += 76;
                g = ((int)((float)(input - 65) / 10) * 100);
                g += 153;
                b = ((int)((float)(input - 65) / 10) * 25);
            }
            else
            {
                r = 0;
                g = 255;
                b = 0;
            }
        }
        r %= 256;
        g %= 256;
        b %= 256;
        valuecolor = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb((byte)r,(byte)g,(byte)b));
        return valuecolor;
    }
}
```

The values are retrieved from a SQLite database and are added to a collection of a custom class. The collection is then set as the DataContext of the chart.

This is what I'm getting so far:
[image: Screenshot of the application]

Please tell me how to set the line colour to be a gradient between the two data point colours joined by the line. Also, please help me fix the legend colours to a constant colour for each lineseries.